# How can I ask for the length of the vector and the user put the values by keyboard?

Tags: python

This is the exercise To solve the previous point, the program is asked to ask the user the size of the vector and then to enter the elements of the vector.
the size of the vector and then enter the elements of the vector.
And this is my code

```
print("Hola! bienvenido")

x = []

n = len(x)

y = 0

while n > 0:
    n=n-1
    y=y+x[n]
    print("El vector X {0} tienen tamaño n = {1} y ala suma de sus componentes es y = {2}".format(x, n, y))
```

Comment: Something to consider: You are creating an empty list called x and then setting n equal to the length of x, which is 0 because it's empty. Your while loop is being skipped because n = 0, which isn't greater than 0

Comment: for asking user you have `input()` - like `text = input()` or `text = input("Write N: ")`. And it always gives string so you have to convert to numbers `n = int(text)`. But `input()` you should show in any tutorial.

Comment: @furas How can I put an invariant in this code?

Comment: did you try to use `input()` like in previous comment?